# convert df from wide to long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a df that looks like this:

[image]

however, i want to convert it to a long df like this:

[image]

how can i achieve this? kindly help, tia

i have tried wide_to_long(), melt & transpose with no success. i am unable to achieve the specific format that i require.

also, if required, the df can be read as csv from this [file](https://jmp.sh/s/Hk106xKqvroszqwbLNXp)

melt does not help me either. i need the year values to be repeated for every distinct month value

Comment: can you Provide a sample of your df as code?

Comment: hi, i have shared the file here https://jmp.sh/s/Hk106xKqvroszqwbLNXp you can read it as csv

Comment: pd.pivot(df_name, index='YEAR', columns='MONTH', values='VALUE')